# Who was on the White Council?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, wizards, government

Does Tolkien ever list the various members of the White Council? How many people were even on it?

### Who was on the White Council?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [The members of the **First White Council**](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/White_Council#The_Second_Age):

- Gil-galad (leader - named).
- Galadriel? (likely, but unknown)
- Elrond (implied - mentioned in quote<sup>1</sup>)
- Círdan (implied - mentioned in quote<sup>1</sup>)
- Other lords of the Eldar? (possible, but unknown)

We don't know much about this council, except that it didn't include any wizards, it met after Sauron's defeat in the Second Age<sup>1</sup>, and [it decided to relocate the Elves from Eregion to Imladris](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Rivendell) (aka Rivendell)<sup>1</sup>.  Also, the three Elven rings were distributed here.

---

### [The members of the **Second White Council**](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/White_Council#The_Third_Age):

- Saruman (leader - called "Curunír")
- Gandalf (called "Mithrandir")
- Galadriel
- Elrond
- Círdan
- Other lords of the Eldar

Tolkien mentions that there were "other lords of the Eldar" on the council, but never names these others.

> But at length the Shadow returned and its power increased; and in that time was first made the Council of the Wise that is called the White Council, and therein were **Elrond and Galadriel and Círdan, and other lords of the Eldar, and with them were Mithrandir and Curunír**. And Curunír (that was Saruman the White) was chosen to be their chief, for he had most studied the devices of Sauron of old. Galadriel indeed had wished that Mithrandir should be the Lead of the Council, and Saruman begrudged them that, for his pride and desire of mastery was grown great; but Mithrandir refused the office, since he would have no ties and no allegiance, save to those who sent him, and he would abide in no place nor be subject to any summons. But Saruman now began to study the lore of the Rings of Power, their making and their history. 
>   -  *Silmarillion:  Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*

---

<sup>1</sup>J.R.R. Tolkien, *Unfinished Tales, "The History of Galadriel and Celeborn", "Concerning Galadriel and Celeborn"*

> [I]t was there determined that an Elvish stronghold in the east of Eriador should be maintained at Imladris rather than in Eregion. At that time also Gil-galad gave Vilya, the Blue Ring, to Elrond, and appointed him to be his vice-regent in Eriador; but the Red Ring he kept, until he gave it to Círdan when he set out from Lindon in the days of the Last Alliance.

Answer (score 6):

- ### Saruman (the leader of the Council)
- ### Gandalf
- ### Elrond
- ### Galadriel
- ### Círdan
- other (unnamed) lords of the Eldar

From the *Silmarillion*, section "Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age" (emphasis mine):

> But at length the Shadow returned and its power increased; and in that time was first made the Council of the Wise that is called **the White Council, and therein were Elrond and Galadriel and Círdan, and other lords of the Eldar, and with them were Mithrandir and Curunír**. And Curunír (that was Saruman the White) was chosen to be their chief, for he had most studied the devices of Sauron of old. Galadriel indeed had wished that Mithrandir should be the Lead of the Council, and Saruman begrudged them that, for his pride and desire of mastery was grown great; but Mithrandir refused the office, since he would have no ties and no allegiance, save to those who sent him, and he would abide in no place nor be subject to any summons.

There were only four recorded meetings of the White Council, in the years 2463, 2851, 2941, and 2953 of the Third Age. It is not confirmed whether or not the same set of members showed up to each meeting.

---

Interestingly, there was also a White Council in the Second Age, which the one formed in the year T.A. 2463 might have been named in honour of. From *Unfinished Tales*, section "Concerning Galadriel and Celeborn":

> At this time [around S.A. 1701] the first Council<sup>10</sup> was held, and it was there determined that an Elvish stronghold in the east of Eriador should be maintained at Imladris rather than in Eregion. At that time also Gil-galad gave Vilya, the Blue Ring, to Elrond, and appointed him to be his vice-regent in Eriador; but the Red Ring he kept, until he gave it to Círdan when he set out from Lindon in the days of the Last Alliance.
>
> <sup>10</sup> <sub>This was later amended to "the first White Council".</sub>